# Getting the height of a child div part not overfloating out of the parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have a parent div with a certain height and a child div with a greater height, typing something like `document.getElementById("#id).style.height` would give me the whole height of the child. How do I get only the height of this part of the child div still in the parent div?

Thank you very much in advance for answers and excuse me, if I didn't use technically correct words.

Comment: that's actually very easy thing but if you have any progress only then i can help you out i cannot make it from scratch

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, You can calculate :

remaining height in parent = bottom position of parent - top position of child

```js
let parent = document.getElementById("parent")
let child = document.getElementById("child")
console.log(parent.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - child.getBoundingClientRect().top)
```

```css
#parent{
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.some-element{
  height: 5px;
}
#child{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-element"></div>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="some-element"></div>
  <div id="child">Child</div><!-- 300 - 5 = 295px inside the parent-->
  <div class="some-element"></div>
</div>
<div class="some-element"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1:**

you can use .parentNode to get parent (if you don't have directly access to parent), then get height of parent, it have to be same as part of the child div still in the parent div, something like:

```
document.getElementById("#id).parentNode.style.height
```

**solution 2:** (this will work even if child div moved)

if access to parent is not the problem, you need a more accurate solution, you can get coordinate of parent and child, then with a little math you have exact part of child in parent div...

```
let parentCoord = document.getElementById('parentId').getBoundingClientRect();
let childCoord = document.getElementById('childId').getBoundingClientRect();
var left = Math.max(parentCoord.left, childCoord.left);
var right = Math.min(parentCoord.right, childCoord.right);
var top = Math.max(parentCoord.top, childCoord.top);
var bottom = Math.min(parentCoord.bottom, childCoord.bottom);
```

now you have exact coords of that part of child in parent div, if you need a width you can do a simple math:

```
var width = right - left;
var height = bottom - top;
```

if this is not what you need then we need a little more details about what you are trying to do...
if this is, then enjoy codding...

Comment: this way it will only get parent height which can also be achieved by selecting parent directly he wants only the visible height of child inside a parent and subtract overflow from child

Comment: @AmirRahman right, he is not mentioning anything about visible that part, he need that part width and that have to be same as parent width,  just if child div moved from default place, my first solution not working well, i updated with a more accurate solution.